# PostgreSQL (9.6.5) Converting Between Time Zones Returning Time Stamp Without Time Zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

Let's start with a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    ts_tz timestamp with time zone
);
```

Let's insert one row of data:

```
INSERT INTO
    test (ts_tz)
VALUES
    (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-08-12 10:22:31.949271-00')
;
```

Now, let's query this one row:

```
postgres=# select * from test;
             ts_tz             
-------------------------------
 2016-08-12 03:22:31.949271-07
```

Ok, this makes sense to me so far. `ts_tz` is a timestamp with time zone and it's displaying as 03:22 with an offset of -07 because that's what my time zone is.

Now, suppose I want to change the time zone to 'US/Pacific'.

```
postgres=# select ts_tz AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' from test;
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2016-08-12 03:22:31.949271
```

But now this returns a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE.

Why is this? How do I keep it as a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE?

Answer (score 1):

This is how `AT TIME ZONE` construct works - timestamptz becomes `timestamp without timezone` and vice versa:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT
[image]

If you want `timestamp with zone` at some time zone specified use `SET`, eg:

```
t=# set timezone to 'EST';
SET
t=#  select * from test;
             ts_tz
-------------------------------
 2016-08-12 05:22:31.949271-05
(1 row)
```